# axis2 wsdl2java command line against web services with ntlm authentication

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, ntlm, wsdl2java

I want to generate web services stubs with apache axis2 wsdl2java through command line, but the problem is, the WSDL url is using NTLM authentication and i always having 401 error. 
my question is there anyway to generate the stub from Web Service with ntlm authentication with Apache Axis2 wsdl2java command line ?

Comment: Downloading the wsdl to the local storage is not an option?

Comment: Thanks, i didn't think of that, i will try your suggestion.